# Giving priority to GIT in GIT/SVN mixed project in Netbeans?

Tags: git, svn, netbeans

Any idea how it possible to indicate to Netbeans I want GIT to be the code version system of choice?

Currently it insists using SVN which I use as external project repo.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how your project is set up?

Comment: I have a project checkout from external SVN source, which I'm pushing into our internal GIT repo. So both .git and .svn folders are present within project structure. Command line tools work fine, the problem is that Netbeans sees only SVN project, and doesn't give any way to switch to GIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(workaround, not actual solution)

The simplest way would be to clone the git repo, pointing your NetBeans instance to that set of files (the cloned git repo).

When you want to go back to the SVN/Git repo, in a command-line session go back to that first mixed repo, git pull from the second repo (to get back all the changes), and proceed in NetBeans, set up to read that first mixed repo, and working primarily with SVN.

Comment: So in short, your idea is to work with git based repo in Netbeans, but have another one for manual update/pull via command line? Sounds interesting, but I wonder if there any solution on IDE level.

Comment: @SyBer I didn't find one IDE-based solution supporting both git and SVN, which is why I proposed to keep them separated.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I have both `.svn` and `.git` directories under single NetBeans project. In such cases NetBeans always uses SVN repository as primary (and only) one.

My solution was to simply disable SVN support in NetBeans (`Tools > Plugins > Installed > Subversion > Deactivate`). That way I can use my console to manage SVN and to have Git repository in NetBeans. Also SVN support can be quickly enable again if needed.

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I also had to use the "Show Details" checkbox (got that from another post, after this one gave the method to me!)

> Tools-Plugins and in the Installed tab mark "Show details" checkbox,
>   select Subversion and hit Deactivate